# Converting google maps into PDF format using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps-markers

I am able to create the maps using the library http://biostall.com/demos/google-maps-v3-api-codeigniter-library/

**Controller:**

```
$this->load->library('googlemaps');

$config['center'] = '37.4419, -122.1419';
$config['zoom'] = 'auto';
$this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

$marker = array();
$marker['position'] = '37.429, -122.1419';
$this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);

$data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();

$this->load->view('view_file', $data);
```

**View:**

```
<html>
<head><?php echo $map['js']; ?></head>
<body><?php echo $map['html']; ?></body>
</html>
```

By lot of samples provided by the library we are able to create the map  and also able to add markers, text and symbols.

I tried with some sample code mentioned below:

**MAP to PDF:**

```
require("fpdf17/fpdf.php");

$pdf = new FPDF( );

   $pdf->AddPage();

   $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);     

   $pdf->Image('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Uk&zoom=12&size=400x400&sensor=false&format=jpg',50,20,100,100,'JPG');

   $pdf->Output("test.pdf");
```

By using the above code i can get the PDF but it just get the map alone not its attributes or properties like markers, symbols etc.

Can we use any class which helps to get the map and its attributes to PDF.
 Does CI allows to capture the parameters from the HTML as the map have markers and other text as attributes?

Any suggestion will value thanks.

Comment: Hi NEW. I created the Google Map library that you mention. The library you're using generates a normal scrollable, draggable, zoomable Google Map. I'm not sure it's even possible to put this into a PDF.

However, I do have a similar Codeigniter library that does a static map and outputs an image which you can view here:

http://biostall.com/codeigniter-library-google-static-maps-api

Try that and let me know how you get on :)

Answer (score 1):

Both maps are differents, if you want to add marks or attributes to your staticmap you need to use this [API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps).
For example, if you want to add a mark you have to add this code to your url.

```
&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794
```

Answer (score 0):

You are working with two different things. In your pdf library, the url you are looking up doesn't know anything about the parameters you've set, because you are looking at google.com, not your site.

You'll need to capture the view you created of the map & make THAT your pdf, I think

Comment: the script which i have tried needs URL as mandatory, but the MAP which will be generated by CI library doesn't need the URL.I am just trying the alternative methods to get the solution.

Comment: AS CI generates MAP in the form of HTML, so i am trying to look for a PDF class which can help to capture the params and set to PDF

Comment: I think the googlemaps works with both js & html to create the map.

So, what i would try is to use the url to that view as the ->Image() url in your second library - in other words, look back at your own site to see the generated page.

However, I couldn't tell you if the js stuff will be picked up or not.